# undefined method `image' if joins tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_comments
 has_many :users, through: :user_comments
 has_attached_file :image
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage/.*\z/
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_comments
 has_many :photos, through: :user_comments
end

class UserComment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :photo
 belongs_to :user
end
```

execute [union = UserComment.joins(:user,:photo).where('photos.id = ?',1).first]- OK

execute [union.image] - ERROR
NoMethodError: undefined method `image' for #UserComment:0x007fe8845fbf58

how fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to access `image` through `photo` association

```
union.photo.image
```